# Button Width in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

Need a little `GridbagLayout` guidance. Please see code below. What I want is for button2 to be twice as wide as buttons 1, 3, and 4. However, all four are actually being displayed with the same width. Obviously doing something wrong, but I can’t figure out what.

Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridbagLayoutTetst {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 250);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        panel.setLayout(gridbag);

        JButton button0 = new JButton("Button 0");
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button0, c);
        panel.add(button0);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button1, c);
        panel.add(button1);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button2, c);
        panel.add(button2);

        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button3, c);
        panel.add(button3);

        JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button4, c);
        panel.add(button4);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
            );
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            //
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: The `c.gridwidth` defines how many columns a component uses. Do you want to change that? I guess you want to use `c.weightx`.. ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, by using a combination of `fill`, `setPreferredSize` and `weightx` I achieved the result I wanted. See below. Now button2 is always twice as wide as the other buttons in that row, even when I resize the frame. Just feels like a hack to me. Would appreciate guidance on the "preferred" way of doing this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridbagLayoutTetst {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 250);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        panel.setLayout(gridbag);

        JButton button0 = new JButton("Button 0");
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button0, c);
        panel.add(button0);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (0,28));
        c.weightx = 0.2;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button1, c);
        panel.add(button1);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (0,28));
        c.weightx = 0.4;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button2, c);
        panel.add(button2);

        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (0,28));
        c.weightx = 0.2;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button3, c);
        panel.add(button3);

        JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (0,28));
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gridbag.setConstraints(button4, c);
        panel.add(button4);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println(button1.getPreferredSize());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
            );
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            //
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```